# Use nuget package instead of project reference Visual studio

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, nuget-package, .net-6.0

We have a solution with 7 to 8 different projects including class libraries and mvc apps. We are using .net 4.6.2 and netstandard 2.0.

We are trying to convert class libraries to nuget packages and instead of referencing the projects directly in our web apps, use nuget packages. We have created the packages and added them in packages.config and the packages are getting installed perfectly fine.

Now, when I remove previous reference and add a new reference and point it to the nuget package, my web apps doesn't work and give assembly not found error.

I think I'm not adding the reference correctly , and need help on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using NuGet packages now then you would install the package into each project which needs the assemblies and NuGet will add the references for you. You don't add the references by adding them from the packages directory.

E.g. Install-Package MyPackage MyProject

Comment: Thanks @Michael Ciba I did that as well, but in one of the project which is a class library that include configurations.context etc can't access the constructor method defined in my nuget project. "Could not load type 'Configuration' from assembly 'NugetCommon, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'."

Comment: The issue is with the static classes. If I add direct project reference I can access the static classes, but if I add reference to the nuget package only static class is inaccessible the rest work fine.